# Python dataframe group labeling

Tags: python, pandas, segment, labeling

Is there any tool in Pandas or other python package to facilitate the labeling of groups of varying number rows in a Pandas’ dataFrame? Here are more detail:

My dataFrame has a column of datetime.datetime objects used as the dataFrame index. The time is not evenly spaced and during a given amount of time, the number of rows varies.

In that dataFrame, I need to make a column that has a different label for each series of rows that span over a constant time span (12 seconds in my case).

For example, using examples with seconds

```
Time(s) | label
1           |   0
2           |   0
3           |   0
7           |   0
12         |   1
15         |   1
20         |   1
24          |   2 
Etc…
```

I’m looking for an alternative as a brute-force loop. Algorithms somewhat related to that are labeling, segmenting, mapping but i'm not sure what to look for exactly. I was hoping there would be something exploiting python, Pandas and/or Numpy in a more efficient way since the number of rows is gonna be of the order of a hundred millions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo:

Sample DF:

```
In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00:01', freq='3S', periods=15)})

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
                  Time
0  2017-01-01 00:00:01
1  2017-01-01 00:00:04
2  2017-01-01 00:00:07
3  2017-01-01 00:00:10
4  2017-01-01 00:00:13
5  2017-01-01 00:00:16
6  2017-01-01 00:00:19
7  2017-01-01 00:00:22
8  2017-01-01 00:00:25
9  2017-01-01 00:00:28
10 2017-01-01 00:00:31
11 2017-01-01 00:00:34
12 2017-01-01 00:00:37
13 2017-01-01 00:00:40
14 2017-01-01 00:00:43
```

Solution:

```
In [34]: df['label'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='12S')).ngroup()
```

Result:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
                  Time  label
0  2017-01-01 00:00:01      0
1  2017-01-01 00:00:04      0
2  2017-01-01 00:00:07      0
3  2017-01-01 00:00:10      0
4  2017-01-01 00:00:13      1
5  2017-01-01 00:00:16      1
6  2017-01-01 00:00:19      1
7  2017-01-01 00:00:22      1
8  2017-01-01 00:00:25      2
9  2017-01-01 00:00:28      2
10 2017-01-01 00:00:31      2
11 2017-01-01 00:00:34      2
12 2017-01-01 00:00:37      3
13 2017-01-01 00:00:40      3
14 2017-01-01 00:00:43      3
```

Comment: Doesn't the **freq** option assume a constant number of entries per blocks of 12s? Your example satifies this as it's generated with a given frequency but as I described, in my case, a given block spanning over 12s does not span over a constant number of rows as those 12s are sampled at random. Would that work also in that case?

Comment: Any idea why it does not work if the 'Time' column is set as the index of the dataFrame?  In that case I had `pd.Grouper(key='index', freq='12S')`. This is resulting in:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'`

Comment: @Wall-E, if `Time` is set as an index, use: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12S')).ngroup()`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, and Time(s) is an integer dtype, then I think what you need is the floordiv.

```
df['label'] = df['Time(s)'] // 12
```